# Javascript Timed Message

Tags: javascript, time, settimeout, alert, timed

I'm trying to make a timed alert that goes off at midnight, and the code so far:

```
function startTime() {
    var today=new Date();
    var h=today.getHours();
    var m=today.getMinutes();
    var s=today.getSeconds();
    h = checkTime(h);
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);

    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},1000);

    if (h==0&&m==0&&s==0){window.alert("The date is "+new Date()); location.reload();}
}
```

goes off at every hour, not every 24 hours like it should. I also could not find where the bug is because it all looks like it should work. Can you please help me?

Comment: why do you need checkTime() for? your code should work fine without it

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I got the code from a website and heavily modified some parts of it and the checkTime() was part of it, so I thought it was important.